# What Happened to Mono 2.11.X?

Tags: c#, mono

This is probably going to sound like a stupid question - what the heck happened to the Mono 2.11.X branches?

I am trying to compile several C# assemblies that require features that were introduced in the 2.11.X branch and I could have sworn that back in late 2012 I saw and read several announcements about its release. A Google search also confirms this.

Now when I go to the downloads page, I see the latest version is 2.10.X! What's going on? I found an archived link to download it but I see the last time it was modified was back in September 2012.

This is the first time I am actually using Mono so if there is anyone familiar with it or their development cycle, can confirm whether or not I should use it? In particular, I want to use the Entity Framework, which should be available in 2.11.X and is currently NOT available in the "latest" 2.10.X.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some random distribution.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I realize it might seem a bit awkward but I don't think it is about a random distribution. The entire documentation and their roadmap states that certain features have been ported since that version. Now I can't find that version and I am asking if someone using Mono knows which version I should use as an alterative, or if there is a workaround to using the current version.

Comment: Random or not, this question is more for the developers of the software, not for [so].

Comment: @JohnSaunders I would like to take my chances and see if someone using Mono has run into a similar problem and how they got it to work. I can reword my question to something like "Overcoming Mono compiler error X to get Entity Framework working with latest distribution" if that would make it more on-topic.

Comment: Now it is mono 3.0.x and 2.10.x, you have to `git clone` and `make` from source yourself.

Comment: FYI, this is not a discussion forum. It's a Q&A site. Please read the [faq]. In my opinion, your question does not belong here.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I know it's a Q&A site - hence my specific question on which alternative version of Mono supports the features added to 2.11. I was not asking for a discussion. My working might be a little off though. You're entitled to your opinion and your vote, which I respect but disagree with. In any case, I got the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @linquize Thank you for your input. I might download 3.0 right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I have seen on their list is that the last stable release is the 2.10.x, they will be maintaining it for about 6 months and are encouraging everyone to use the 3.0 branch even though it is still stated as beta. http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.0

From above link:

> Mono 3.0 is an update to Mono 2.10 based on the master branch of github, it is not a minor upgrade to 2.10. Mono 3.0 was released on October 18th 2012.
>
> We will continue to bug fix and update Mono 2.10 for another six months for users that can not upgrade to Mono 3.0.
>
> New Microsoft Open Source Stacks
>
> We now include the following assemblies as part of Mono from
> Microsoft's ASP.NET WebStack:
> System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
> System.Web.Http.dll
> System.Web.Razor.dll
> System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
> System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
> System.Web.WebPages.dll
> System.Web.Mvc.dll
> System.Json.dll
> (Previously available in Mono, but now replaced with Microsoft's
> implementation)
>
> We also bundle the recently open sourced Entity Framework and
> **EntityFramework.dll**

Answer (score 1):

From Miguel's blog post, you can see that in fact Mono 2.11.* becomes 3.0.*,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Oct-22.html

This post discusses about Mono 3.0.*, but it links to an old post about Mono 2.11.*.

They should have avoided to skip 2.11.*, as so far it leads most of the confusion. But I have to confess that Mono 3 sounds cooler.

If you want to use any new features, as @MarkHall explained you should use Mono 3.0.*.

In this case, search engines are less useful, as they cannot tell you enough history about a project via algorithms at this moment. If you want to know better about Mono, make sure you subscribe to its mail list, RSS feeds, and so on.